# Calculate the flux of $F=(x, y, z)$ through a unit hemisphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked the following question:

> The surface $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the unity of $$K=\{(x, y, z)|z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},\; z\geq 0\},$$ and $$C = \{(x, y, z) | x^2 + y^2 \leq 0,\;  z=0\}.$$
>
> Given is a vectorfield $F = xi + yj + zk$. Calculate the flux of $F$ through $\Sigma$ with an outward pointing normal.

I approached this question through use of the divergence theorem and would like to figure out where and if I made a mistake (kinda sceptical of the answer I found).

**solution**

Note that $K$ represents the upper hemisphere and $C$ represents its bottom. The divergence theorem tells us that the flux is equal to $$\int\int\int_R \nabla\cdot Fdxdydz,$$ where $R$ is the object in question. We will calculate this by parts, first calculating the flux through $K$ and then through $C$.

Since $\nabla\cdot F = 3$, we're only really concerned with finding the appropriate bounds for the integrals. Given that $K$ is the upper unit hemisphere, we can consider a switch to polar coordinates with $$0\leq \rho \leq 1,\quad -\frac12 \pi \leq \theta \leq \frac12\pi,\quad 0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$$ to find that the flux through $K$ equals $$2\pi\int_0^1\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\rho ^2 \sin(\phi)d\phi d\rho.$$
Note that the sine is symmetric over any interval $[-x, x]$, and so particularily in this case. Therefore the integral evaluates to $0$.

Similarly, due to symmetry along the line $y = -x$, the flux through the disk $C$ also evaluates to $0$; so that the total flux equals $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By divergence theorem, since here the divergence of $F$ is constant, the flux is $\text{div}(F)=3$ times the volume of the solid, the half-sphere of radius $1$ which is $2\pi/3$. So the flux should be $2\pi$. This can be obtained by computing 
$$\text{div}(F)\cdot \text{vol}(R)=3\cdot 2\pi\int_{\rho=0}^1\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\rho ^2 \sin(\phi)d\phi d\rho=2\pi.$$
Note the limits of the angle $\phi$ from $0$ ("north pole") to $\pi$ ( "equator").